# Concurrency of thread

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF application (vb) which works fine but when a user requests information while the server is doing a call to another user, everybody hangs!

Comment: I'm not a WCF expert, but I think you're going to need to provide more information. Does the server really "do a call to another user"? Or do you mean that two users are both calling into the server?

Answer (score 3):

When you configure your service, there are two things you need to configure:

- [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) - which determines how many service instances are created to service the client requests, try use PerCall/PerSession if possible as they allows for the most concurrency.
- [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) - which determines if each service instance is single-threaded or multi-threaded.

Based on the information you've provided so far, I'd recommend changing these two settings and see if it solves your problem:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService { ... }
```

I put a blog post together of the things I learnt whilst doing some performance work on our WCF services a little while back, maybe it'd be of help:

http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/wcf-improve-performance-with-greater-concurrency/